# Creating multiline labels in xy-pics, xy-matrix or similar

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

I would like to make a diagram that shows the order in which i used some models. I normally make diagrams with xy-matrix, but some of the model names would look clumsy if kept on a single line, so I'd like to be able to make them run over separate lines and look something like:

model 1

↓

Model 2

↓

Model 2

simplified

↓

Model 3

I realise that this may be beyond the bounds of what xy-matrix can do, in which case could anyone advise me a quick way of making this kind of diagram with another package?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can do with Xy-pic

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix@R-2ex{
  \txt{Model 1} \ar[d] \\
  \txt{Model 2} \ar[d] \\
  \txt{Model 2\\simplified} \ar[d] \\
  \txt{Model 3}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]